# Xuggler 3.4.1012 for windows with JVM 64bit

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

i installed xuggler for jvm 32bit from here http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Preview+Generation, it worked perfectly, but now i need this for 64bit jvm, can anyone help?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have Liferay download the version for you: Go to ControlPanel/Server/Server Administration/External Services (at least on tomcat this is the easiest way, I'm not sure about other platforms)

The platforms there explicitly list win64 and you can be reasonably sure to get the supported version.

Update: I found this in portal.properties. You can construct the [URL](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/xuggle-xuggler-arch-x86_64-w64-mingw32.jar) from this:

```
#
# Set the properties used to install Xuggler at runtime.
#
xuggler.jar.file[32-linux]=xuggle-xuggler-arch-i686-pc-linux-gnu.jar
xuggler.jar.file[32-mac]=xuggle-xuggler-arch-i386-xuggle-darwin11.jar
xuggler.jar.file[32-win]=xuggle-xuggler-arch-i686-w64-mingw32.jar
xuggler.jar.file[64-linux]=xuggle-xuggler-arch-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.jar
xuggler.jar.file[64-mac]=xuggle-xuggler-arch-x86_64-xuggle-darwin11.jar
xuggler.jar.file[64-win]=xuggle-xuggler-arch-x86_64-w64-mingw32.jar
xuggler.jar.name[32-linux]=Linux 32-bit JVM (with GNU libc v6)
xuggler.jar.name[32-mac]=Mac OS X 10.7 32-bit JVM
xuggler.jar.name[32-win]=Windows 32-bit JVM
xuggler.jar.name[64-linux]=Linux 64-bit JVM (with GNU libc v6)
xuggler.jar.name[64-mac]=Mac OS X 10.7 64-bit JVM
xuggler.jar.name[64-win]=Windows 64-bit JVM
xuggler.jar.options=32-linux,32-mac,32-win,64-linux,64-mac,64-win
xuggler.jar.url=http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/
```

Comment: so? Just do as I say: Go to ControlPanel. In the given location is a download link - this will download right into Liferay. Once it's done just restart.

Comment: there is no download or install option in 6.1.0 version, it is in 6.1.1.
but i want to do in liferay 6.1.0.

Comment: ah - I see, sorry. Can you work around this, use 6.1.1 to download and then copy the downloaded versions from the 6.1.1 installation in tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib ?